# Any comparative adverbs here?

Tags: adverbs, gerunds, comparative

> I have much more inspiration, and the editing would be easier.

Is "the editing" a gerund? If so, is "easier" being used as a comparative adjective?

Comment: "Editing" is a noun, and "easier" is a comparative adjective. "More" is a determinative, and "much" is a degree adverb modifying "more".

Comment: There's a ***serious*** mismatch of ***verb tenses*** in your example. Either change the first one to *I **would have** much more inspiration*, or change the second to *the editing **is / will be** easier*.

Answer (score 1):

"Editing" is a noun as evident from the presence of the definite article "the". A verb doesn't take an article. However, this noun derived from the gerundial form of the verb "edit".

Yes. "Easier" is a comparative adjective. Comparative adjectives are formed inflectionally by the comparative suffix *-er* or analytically by the adverb "more".

The secondary term of comparison is missing and implied here. Without context, the sentence is understood as " the editing is easier *than it was*".